# GWT Pass Config Vars From Server to Client

Tags: gwt, dictionary, properties, client-server, config

On startup of my application i would like to make an rpc call form the client to the server. The call would result in the server creating a Properties object from a .properties file and passing it back to the client. However this does not seem to be possible as when i do this i get an error "No source code is available for type java.util.Properties; did you forget to inherit a required module?". I then tried to use a GWT Dictionary instead but doing so resulted in a error because a dictionary object is not serializable. Any ideas of how to fix either of the above 2 errors or of another way of doing this.

Comment: Ever thought about using http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideI18n.html#DevGuideDynamicStringInternationalization for including properties? You basically include a .js file which contains a map of your properties that can be accessed in your GWT code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass java.util.Properties back to client in RPC. The list of java classes in GWT that are emulated is listed http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html

Also you should process the properties file into a model/pojo class in serializable java class and pass it back in RPC. You can use JSON object to do the same.

In any case you should process the properties file on server side into a format that is acceptable to GWT via JSON or RequestFactory or RPC.